# Suitable Optimization technique for my analysis and supporting codes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have five input parameters a,b,c,d,e which are interdependent of each other. I would like to find the optimized values of a,b,c,d,e to find efficient frequency (Frequency depends on 5 parameters).

```
For example,
a varies from 0 to A;
b varies from 0 to B;
c varies from 0 to C;
d varies from 0 to D;
e varies from 0 to E;
```

If I perform one by one parameter optimization, the optimized result is not efficient. Which optimization technique is suitable for my analysis. Where can I find MATLAB code  for such optimization (multiple iterations and comparative evaluation)?? It will be really helpful if you can help me to decide a technique.

Comment: `fminbnd` seems appropriate at first sight: it seeks optimal solutions under bound constraints.

Comment: The output parameter 'frequency' is not a function of single parameter 'x' whose values lies between x1 and x2. But the frequency is a function of 5 parameters like a, b, c, d, e. (i.e.) frequency=function(a,b,c,d,e) where a>0, b>0, c>0, d>0, e>0. How to find non zero optimal solution of a, b, c, d, e to obtain minimum value of frequency.???

Comment: Sorry. Fmincon allows bound s.

Comment: Thank you so much... I think this command will be helpful for my optimization...